Flask error related with SERVER_NAME after upgrading to Flask 3.1.0
My application uses subdomains (every logged user has his own: user.domain.com) and Blueprints with no subdomains.
Till now I didn't set subdomain_matching and I set
SERVER_NAME = "domain.com" and SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.com".
After upgrading to Flask 3.1.0 from 3.0.3 the application is not working anymore and every url is requested gets 404 error (but error page is correctly loaded).
If I delete the "subdomain" parameter from routes, then www.domain.com is working but I can't get username.domain.com.
I see in Flask documentation "Changes" section that something has changed in 3.1.0 about SERVER_NAME, but I can't understand how this parameter has to be set in order to have subdomains working.

The solution seems quite simple: subdomain_matching has to be enabled.
app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)

The problem IMO is that in this moment Flask documentation is not so clear about this, it helped reading #5553.
In particular, I quote the documentation:
SERVER_NAME
"Must be set if subdomain_matching is enabled, to be able to extract the subdomain from the request."
but I couldn't find where it explicitly says that since 3.1.0 setting SERVER_NAME alone doesn't activate sudomain_matching anymore.
